# Measuring response time for IDAS & Context Broker Fiware

Tags: rest, web-services, fiware, evaluation, fiware-orion

I am using the IDAS and Context Broker Fiware's services and i would like to measure their response time in order to evaluate my back-end.

How could i make some tests and measure them?

I would like to calculate the time in which my Data are transmitted from the MQTT broker to the Context Broker via IDAS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Every requests and responses are logged in both sides, so you can get both times (Requests & Responses Times) to get details and do an average.

Thanks
Fernando